# FTP GUI client for Unix-like platform capable of TLS/SSL/SFTP

Tags: linux, user-interface, ftp, sftp, ssl

I know similar questions were already asked and answered, but not exactly the same.

I'm looking for a FTP client that can do TLS/SSL connection and SFTP aswell on Linux with a nice GUI. This is main requirement, though tabbed session are a plus.

FTPRush is my idol for FTP-ing on Windows, something similar on linux would be a rockstar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filezilla? http://filezilla-project.org/

Comment: Filezilla is pretty awsome at first sight. However, it constantly crashes and is not multi-threaded (tabbed).

Comment: I've not used it on Linux, but it's rock-solid on Windows ... so maybe its something they're working on. It might be more stable if built from sources? I don't know what dist you're using. Also can you clarify/confirm why you want a tabbed view -- is this to support connecting simultaneously to *different* sites? If not, FZ already multi-threads downloads.

Comment: I want tabbed view because mostly I connect to more sites at the time.

Comment: @iElectric -- it's several months later, but just a heads-up. FileZilla now has tabbed connections as of 3.3.0. If you've been using it, you'll probably have got a nag about it the new version; if not - just thought I'd drop you a note.

Comment: Small but imporant note: filezilla does not support FXP. Bummer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Gnome, then I'd recommend just using Nautilus.  It will do at SFTP and FTP, I'm not sure about FTP with SSL.  It will also do tabs.

Comment: This is what I'm using ATM, still missing proper TLS/SSL support.

Answer (score 1):

Konqueror can do SFTP as well as ftp over ssh.

Answer (score 1):

FireFTP firefox extension.

Answer (score 1):

Try [CrossFTP](http://www.crossftp.com/features.htm)

Comment: Thanks for recommendation Phill, but most of features are payable. Ofcourse, this is out of the question:(

Comment: @iElectric: For-fee software is *not* out of the question. If you had wanted it to be out of the question, you should have said so *in* the question. People shouldn't have to guess what question you meant to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia shows ( [that table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_FTP_client_software#Protocol_support) ) with "Information about what internet protocols the clients support" and ([another one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_FTP_client_software#Operating_system_support)) with "The operating systems the clients can run on."
Just merge it!

HTH and Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[gFTP](http://gftp.seul.org/) should do as well

Comment: gFTP is not tabbed (allows only one transfer per window) and does not support SSL/TLS

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iglooftp.com/unix/

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibles.

Kasablanca - KDE based.
http://kasablanca.berlios.de

Another one.  Igloo ftp
http://www.iglooftp.com/unix/

Comment: iglooftp looks promisiong, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do this but maybe run FTPRush in [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/)? Just a thought

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem so I can safely say that you probably won't find the silver bullet you are looking for. The FTP clients currently available on Linux just don't compare to some of the Windows clients. Having searched and searched I had to settle with gFTP and FileZilla. However there is another that is decent which hasn't been mentioned yet: [FireFTP](http://fireftp.mozdev.org/). It is an extension to Firefox so that in itself has it's own set of pro's and con's.

Before you give up though, you should test drive [CrossOver](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/cxlinux/) and use it to install FTPRush and see if it works. It's at least worth a try.

Comment: The command line clients are quite good (i.e. lftp) which is probably why there isn't that much interest in the gui clients.

Answer (score 0):

Also `gigolo` works to do that. It's very useful when nautilus is not available (i.e. when using Linux with LXDE). Gigolo establish connection and later with a file manager is possible open as a local folder.